# MS Word typing in Red as default in a doc that is black font

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I've  a document which is in black font as usual. I need to make some comments inline at various points which I want in Red. I can select and change each text block and that works. However that takes a lot of selecting.

I tried changing to Red the Font Color icon however everytime you type it reverts to the default style of the block which is black.

Is there a way to set the font color so that all the text I type from now on will be in red irrespective of the black text in the rest of the doc?

Comment: If you aren't able to find a solution, I recommend using AutoHotKey or `xdotool` (for linux) to automate the changing of black to red using a keyboard macro. This might be a lot of work to program for just a small doc but scales well for larger or multiple documents, instead of manually clicking and changing to red

Comment: This isn't precisely what you were asking for, but if you use Track Changes, you can add in text, and the person you send the doc to will be able to see your additions in a different colour.